# How to bind list of Enviroment Variables to Options in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables, app-config, ioptions

I have a list of environment variables located on kubernetes pod where my application is hosted, it`s have no sections, only list of variables that looks like this:

```
KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
KAFKA_PASSWORD
KAFKA_TOPIC
KAFKA_USERNAME
```

what is best way to map it to my options class

```
[ConfigurationKeyName("KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS")]
public required string BootstrapServers { get; set; }
[ConfigurationKeyName("KAFKA_USERNAME")]
public required string Username { get; set; }
[ConfigurationKeyName("KAFKA_PASSWORD")]
public required string Password { get; set; }
[ConfigurationKeyName("KAFKA_TOPIC")]
public required string Topic { get; set; }
```

I tries to bind via `IConfigureOptions<KafkaOptions>` via interface, but its demanding ConfigurationSection to bind for, that i don't have

```cs
_configuration
     .GetSection(SectionName)
      .Bind(options);
```

Can anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: What is `_configuration`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind from the config itself (requires `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder`):

```
public void Configure(TestOptions options)
{
    _configuration.Bind(options);
}
```

Personally I would use the double underscore separator (`__`, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#non-prefixed-environment-variables)) after `KAFKA` which would allow to use `KAFKA` as section (env variables should look like: `KAFKA__BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` etc.):

```
// in the IConfigureOptions
_configuration.GetSection("KAFKA").Bind(options);

// in the settings class
[ConfigurationKeyName("BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS")]
public required string BootstrapServers { get; set; }
[ConfigurationKeyName("USERNAME")]
public required string Username { get; set; }
// ...
```